# AzureML: How to delete detached Kubernetes service clusters?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

On AzureMl, I have created some Kubernetes service clusters using `ComputeTarget.create()`.

Unfortunately, I have detached some of them and I can no longer see them from the AzureML page (Compute > Inference Clusters). I can re-attach them on the AzureMl page but the delete bottom is not available for the re-attached clusters.

Because those idle clusters occupy the Total Regional Cores quota I can't create new clusters, I am wondering if there is a way to delete them?

Answer (score 0):

When you detach a Compute object from its associated workspace, only their associations are removed but the underlying cloud objects are not deleted. You should be able to delete them using the [delete()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.compute.computetarget?view=azure-ml-py#delete--) method in the same `ComputeTarget` class.

Also, the [azure-cli-ml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-azure-machine-learning-cli) extension in Azure CLI provides similar commands for working with Azure Machine Learning and allows you to automate your machine learning activities.

[az ml computetarget delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-ml/ml/computetarget?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_cli_ml_az_ml_computetarget_delete) would be the Azure CLI equivalent to delete a compute target. Here is the complete [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-ml/ml?view=azure-cli-latest) for the available commands.